# How to generate smaller url bookmarks in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I want to create bookmarks for locally stored files so that the files can be tracked if they are moved to new locations.

My attempts to use Swift 3's NSURL function `bookmarkData(options:includingResourceValuesForKeys:relativeTo)` finds it obligatorily generating bookmark data objects that are almost a megabyte in size, even in cases in which the files themselves are orders of magnitude smaller than that.

For example, for a 4-byte text file, the following code produces 410kb bookmark data.
(Running in AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, OS X, Xcode 8.2)

(Note that when I tried using `NSURL.BookmarkCreationOptions.minimalBookmark`, instead of `.suitableForBookmarkFile`, the output was only 0kb and I could not use it to track the original file.)

Similarly, bookmarking a 19kb .jpg file produces an 888kb bookmark.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, is there a way to get bookmarks that is not quite so greedy?

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/U/test.txt", isDirectory: false)

if let urlBookmark = try? url.bookmarkData(options: .suitableForBookmarkFile, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil) {
    print("bookmark size = \(urlBookmark.count / 1024) kb")
}
```

**Edit**:

From a few further quick and dirty tests, I see that the size of the bookmark is fixed and is determined by the file's *category* rather than by the file's size:

.pages  479kb
.txt    419kb
.pdf    898kb
.numbers  309kb
.jpg    888kb
.png    915kb
.exe    342kb
.mp4  691kb
.mkv  594kb

Still, I would like to know if there is any way within those constraints to get even smaller bookmarks.

Comment: You are counting the size of the bookmark, not of the file. The bookmark data is just  a data that represents an URL, not the content of the file.